# How to validate sub-schemas based on value in parent schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

I am trying to validate a JSON schema using jsonschema lib.

scenario:
I need to make sure if a specific value in a property is sent in the parent object, the child(sub-schema) should also get the same value in the same property.

JSON:->

```
{
"type": "object",
  "properties": {
"action": {
  "enum": [
    "get",
    "post"
  ]
},
"order": {
  "properties": {
    "id": "string",
    "action": {
      "enum": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    }
  }
}},"dependentSchemas": {
"if": {
  "action": {
    "const": "get"
  }
},
"then": {
  "properties": {
    "order": {
      "properties": {
        "action": {
          "const": "get"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

Sample test cases:
Positive:

```
{
"action": "get",
"order": {
   "id" : "1"
   "action": "get"
      }
}
```

Negative:

```
{
"action": "get",
"order": {
   "id" : "2"
   "action": "post"
      }
}
```

I am using dependentSchemas to validate the sub-schema:-[click here](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html#dependentschemas)

Answer (score 1):

`dependentSchemas` isn't going to work for this case. `dependentSchemas` branches on the presence of a property, not it's value. You need to use `if`/`then` to branch on the value of the property.

```json
"allOf": [
  {
    "if": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "action": { "const": "get" }
      },
      "required": ["action"]
    },
    "then": {
      "properties": {
        "order": {
          "action": { "const": "get" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ... Another if/then just like the first but with "post" ...
]
```

Note: the `type` and `required` keywords are necessary in the `if` schema for good error messages in extreme cases.